# Can I check authentication of the user with checking if he has a JWT in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing a simple project and I have to use JWT for my authentication. I've created a registration form and log in page, which gives an authorityToken to user and saves it in localStorage. 
After user logs into his account :

`

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
                      var loginReq = {
                        email: $("#inputEmail").val(),
                        password: $("#inputPassword").val()
                      };

                  $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost:8080/public/signin",
                    type:"POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(loginReq),
                    success:function(data){
                      localStorage.setItem("authorityToken",data);
                      alert("Welcome");
                      window.location.replace("file:///C:/pathtoMyProject/HTML_CSS/Main/main.html");
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                      alert("error");
                    }
                  });
              });`
```

he gets to the main page. I would like main page to have a token check function: if localStorage has a JWT and it is valid then grant access to the website. If not - redirect to log in. I would like main not open and redirect always, if client doesn't have a JWT.

Is it the right way to do? If yes, could you help me to write a proper function, if not, please tell me another way to do it(I am using Java and SpringBoot for my backend) . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(localStorage.getItem("authorityToken")!=null)
 {
// user authenticated 
}
else{
// Not authenticated 
**strong text**
}
```

Comment: It's not working, my friend. It still gives me access to the website.

Comment: When you are doing localStorage.getItem("authorityToken"), what are you getting?

Comment: you need to check the localStorage after redirecting from login page.

Comment: 'function authenticationCheck(){
            if(localStorage.getItem("authorityToken") != null){
                
            } else{
                window.location.replace("file:///C:/path/Sign In/signin.html");
            }
      };'

Comment: you are calling function authenticationCheck on document load?

Comment: ' <script>
    
     $(document).ready(function(){
              function authenticationCheck(){
            if(localStorage.getItem("authorityToken") != null){
                
            } else{
                window.location.replace("file:///C:/Users/kichn/IdeaProjects/localguidefinal/HTML_CSS/Sign In/signin.html");
            }
      };

     };
      
      
    </script> ' I have this code in my header.

Comment: you are declaring the function but not calling it. 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
authenticationCheck();
});
function authenticationCheck(){ 
if(localStorage.getItem("authorityToken") != null)
{
// some code
}
 else{
 window.location.replace("file:///C:/Users/kichn/IdeaProjects/localguidefinal/HTML_CSS/Sign In/signin.html"); 
 }

</script>